# why getElementsByName is giving undefined value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi I have a dropdownlist as a column within a gridview. gridview has multiple rows.
In Page Source of this Page I see same Id for all the drodownlists of each row, but name is differenet. So I want to get the selected value of a dropdownlist in any nth row. So I'm trying to do the same by getElementsByName. But its giving undefind value. 
Why its giving undefined value and how to achieve the desired results

```
var DropDown= document.getElementsByName('grvRewardRulesDetails$ctl03$StartHourDropDown');
```

Comment: grvRewardRulesDetails$ctl03$StartHourDropDown is it a single name or three names combined ?

Comment: please post your html code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementByID('<%= StartHourDropDown.ClientID %>')
```

Your DropDownList(DDL) is inside a GridView.
Then you must try some other things. Try calling the Javascript on the onchange event of DDL

This link should help 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1550471.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solved Issue. 
getElementsByName returns array not a single value.